# Why does this work? Method overloading + method overriding + polymorphism

Tags: c#, polymorphism, overriding, overloading

In the following code:

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
public abstract bool MyMethod(
        Database database,
        AssetDetails asset,
        ref string errorMessage);
}

public sealed class MySubClass : MyClass
{
    public override bool MyMethod(
        Database database,
        AssetDetails asset,
        ref string errorMessage)
    {
        return MyMethod(database, asset, ref errorMessage);
    }

    public bool MyMethod(
        Database database,
        AssetBase asset,
        ref string errorMessage)
    {
    // work is done here
}
}
```

where AssetDetails is a subclass of AssetBase.

Why does the first MyMethod call the second at runtime when passed an AssetDetails, rather than getting stuck in an infinite loop of recursion?

Comment: Haven't you forgot a ` : MyClass` on your `MySubClass` definition?

Comment: 1 - Do you really mean to have MySubClass as an inner class?  Why?
2 - Could you give an example of actually invoking the method to give the behaviour you're describing

Comment: MySubClass isn't an inner class, no. An example would be effectively mySubClassInstance.MyMethod(database, new AssetDetails(), ref msg); - this hits the first method, then is passed to the second

Comment: How is "mysubClassInstance" declared? to be of the base or the descendant type? (regardless of what type you put into it)

Comment: mysubClassInstance was declared as the descendant type.

Comment: kasey, Have you run this program? Because when I did it never calls First method of MySubClass if you pass AssetDetails while invoking MySubClass. Rather it calls second method on this call (meaning final method of MySubclass)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

C# will resolve your call to your other implementation because calls to a method on an object, where the class for that object has its own implementation will be favored over an overridden or inherited one.

This can lead to subtle and hard-to-find problems, like you've shown here.

For instance, try this code (first read it, then compile and execute it), see if it does what you expect it to do.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication9
{
    public class Base
    {
        public virtual void Test(String s)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Base.Test(String=" + s + ")");
        }
    }

    public class Descendant : Base
    {
        public override void Test(String s)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Descendant.Test(String=" + s + ")");
        }

        public void Test(Object s)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Descendant.Test(Object=" + s + ")");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Descendant d = new Descendant();
            d.Test("Test");
            Console.In.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that if you declare the type of the variable to be of type `Base` instead of `Descendant`, the call will go to the other method, try changing this line:

```
Descendant d = new Descendant();
```

to this, and re-run:

```
Base d = new Descendant();
```

So, how would you actually manage to call `Descendant.Test(String)` then?

My first attempt looks like this:

```
public void Test(Object s)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Descendant.Test(Object=" + s + ")");
    Test((String)s);
}
```

This did me no good, and instead just called `Test(Object)` again and again for an eventual stack overflow.

But, the following works. Since, when we declare the `d` variable to be of the `Base` type, we end up calling the right virtual method, we can resort to that trickery as well:

```
public void Test(Object s)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Descendant.Test(Object=" + s + ")");
    Base b = this;
    b.Test((String)s);
}
```

This will print out:

```
Descendant.Test(Object=Test)
Descendant.Test(String=Test)
```

you can also do that from the outside:

```
Descendant d = new Descendant();
d.Test("Test");
Base b = d;
b.Test("Test");
Console.In.ReadLine();
```

will print out the same.

But *first* you **need to be aware of the problem**, which is another thing completely.

Comment: Since there is no way to get into this mess without having one virtual and one non-virtual method (you can't have two identical methods in the same class), or having a method in the base class call a method in a descendant class without having a virtual method, I don't think this factors into it. I'm still not sure about why that matters as you say, there are many such subtle problems, not all of them related to virtual methods. But please enlighten me, and I'll change my answer accordingly, I've only been shown this problem by Jon Skeet, any moment now he'll wake up and prove us all wrong...

Comment: As I understood it, he has, due to overriding the method from the base class, and also implementing it separately, two "identical" methods in his descendant class, and is wondering why the compiler picked one and not the other for his call.

Comment: @Lasse,  Yes, I see that now, you are exactly right. -  sorry I deleted my comment just before you responded.

Comment: Not to worry, this part of the compiler is the dark alley I don't dare venture into anyway, for fear of being mugged :)

Comment: Thanks very much, I was able to predict what your app would output thanks to your explanation, and it was the opposite of what I would have expected before, so I guess that means you answered my question! It's a relief to know there's finally a good reason for it.

Comment: @Lasse, the intriguing thing is looking at who ((what types) have access to the two implementations.  objects of type MySubClass have access only to the non-virtual method.  Objects that derive from MySubClass (if it wasn't sealed), would only have access to the virtual method if they were declared as their concrete type, and would only have access to the non-virtual method if they were declared as MySubClass. Given that it is sealed, and his base is abstyract, in his example there should be no way to access the virtual member at all, no?

Comment: Well, you can internally, through some trickery, let met change my answer.

Comment: And with my changes, you will also in this case have to resort to a cast, so it's a bit contrived.

Answer (score 5):

See the section of the C# Language Specification on [Member Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691331(VS.71).aspx) and [Overload Resolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691340(VS.71).aspx).  The override method of the derived class is not a candidate because of the rules on Member Lookup and the base class method is not the best match based on the Overload Resolution rules.

Section 7.3

> First, the set of all accessible (Section 3.5) members named N declared in T and the base types (Section 7.3.1) of T is constructed. Declarations that include an override modifier are excluded from the set. If no members named N exist and are accessible, then the lookup produces no match, and the following steps are not evaluated.

Section 7.4.2:

> Each of these contexts defines the set of candidate function members and the list of arguments in its own unique way, as described in detail in the sections listed above. For example, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not include methods marked override (Section 7.3), and *methods in a base class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is applicable* (Section 7.5.5.1). (emphasis mine)

Comment: This is the best technical answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

As others have correctly noted, when given the choice between two applicable candidate methods in a class, the compiler *always* chooses the one that was *originally declared* "closer" to the class which contains the call site when examining the base class hierarchy.

This seems counterintuitive. Surely if there is an exact match declared on a base class then this is a better match than an inexact match declared on a derived class, yes?

No. There are two reasons to choose the more derived method always over the less derived method.

The first is that the author of the derived class has much more information than the author of the base class. The author of the derived class knows everything about both the base class *and* the derived class, which is, after all, the class that the caller is actually using. When given the choice between calling a method written by someone who knows everything vs someone who knows only something about the type the caller is using, clearly it makes sense to prioritize calling the method written by the designer of the derived class.

Second, making that choice leads to a form of the Brittle Base Class Failure. We wish to protect you from this failure, and therefore have written the overload resolution rules so as to avoid it whenever possible.

For a detailed explanation of how this rule protects you from the Brittle Base Class Failure, see [my article on the subject](https://web.archive.org/web/20080906132416/http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2007/09/04/future-breaking-changes-part-three.aspx).

And for articles on other ways that languages deal with Brittle Base Class situations, click [here](https://ericlippert.com/category/brittle-base-classes/).

Comment: Thanks; it's very interesting to see the rationale behind the decision.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the way the language is defined.  For *virtual* members, the Implementation which is called at runtime, when a method exists in both a base class and a derived class, is based on the ***concrete type*** of the object which the method is called against, not the *declared* type of the variable which holds the reference to the object.  Your first `MyMethod` is in an abstract class. So it can ***never*** be called from an object of type `MyClass` - because no such object can ever exist.  All you can instanitate is derived class `MySubClass`.  The concrete type is `MySubClass`, so *that* implementation is called, no matter that the code that calls it is in the base class.

For non-virtual members/methods, just the opposite is true.

Comment: Sorry, to clarify: by the "first" MyMethod I meant the first implementation, i.e. the first MyMethod in MySubClass, but the second lexical instantiation.

What's confusing me is why the final occurrence of MyMethod is called when passed an AssetDetails.

Comment: @kasey, Yes, you're correct in that I mis-understood yr question... lasse' answer above is right on target...