# How does string.Format handle null values?

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

In the following code below, why do the two `string.Format` calls not behave the same way? In the first one, no exception is thrown, but in the second one an `ArgumentNullException` is thrown.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Exception e = null;
    string msgOne = string.Format("An exception occurred: {0}", e);
    string msgTwo = string.Format("Another exception occurred: {0}", null);
}
```

Could someone please help me understand the difference between the two?

Comment: Chances are you're hitting the [`params` override](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) in the second example and `String.Format` tests that the array is populated before it proceeds to iterate over the collection and insert values.

Comment: @BradChristie You should write that as an answer.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'm guessing here, but it looks to be the difference of which overloaded call you're hitting;  [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh1dzhdx.aspx) has multiple.

In the first example, it would make sense you're hitting [`String.Format(string,object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx).

In the second example by providing `null` you're most likely hitting [`String.Format(string,params object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) which, per the documentation, would raise an `ArgumentNullException` when:

> format or args is null.

If you're running .NET4, try using named parameters:

```
String.Format("Another exception occured: {0}", arg0: null);
```

Why is it hitting the `params object[]` overload? Probably because `null` isn't an object, and the way `params` works is that you can pass *either* each value as a new object in the call *or* pass it an array of the values. That is to say, the following are [one in the same](http://ideone.com/M9Hl7C):

```
String.Format("Hello, {0}! Today is {1}.", "World", "Sunny");
String.Format("Hello, {0}! Today is {1}.", new Object[]{ "World", "Sunny" })
```

So it's translating your statement call to something along the lines of:

```
String format = "Another exception occured: {0}";
Object[] args = null;
String.Format(format, args); // throw new ArgumentNullException();
```

Comment: Also: Try the difference between `string.Format("Occurred: {0}", (object[])null)` and `string.Format("Occurred: {0}", (object)null)`. There's one more possibility: `string.Format("Occurred: {0}", new[] { (object)null, })`. Problem only happens in the first case, I guess.

Answer (score 12):

In your first example, you are hitting `Format(String, Object)`, which looks like this when disassembled:

```
 public static string Format(string format, object arg0)
 {
    return Format(null, format, new object[] { arg0 });
 }
```

Note the `new object[]` around that.

The second one, you are apparently hitting the `Format(string, object[])` usage, at least that is the one being invoked when I perform the same test.  Disassembled, that looks like this:

```
 public static string Format(string format, params object[] args)
 {
     return Format(null, format, args);
 }
```

So all of these actually get funneled to `Format(IFormatProvider, string, object[])`.  Cool, let's look at the first few lines there:

```
public static string Format(IFormatProvider provider, string format, params object[] args)
{
    if ((format == null) || (args == null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException((format == null) ? "format" : "args");
    }
...
}
```

...welp, there's your problem, right there!  The first invocation is wrapping it in a new array, so it's not null.  Passing in null explicitly doesn't make it do that, due to the specific instance of `Format()` that's calling.

Answer (score 8):

In case you use an interpolated string ($"", another way to format), the null is ignored, skipped. So

```
string nullString = null;
Console.WriteLine($"This is a '{nullString}' in a string");
```

will produce: "This is a '' in a string". Of course you can use the null coalescing operator in case of null to produce the output needed:

```
string nullString = null;
Console.WriteLine($"This is a '{nullString ?? "nothing"}' in a string");
```

Answer (score 2):

The first call gets resolved as a call to Format(object), while the second gets resolved as a call to Format(object[]). Null parameters are handled differently by these different overloads.

Overload resolution is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173339/how-does-the-method-overload-resolution-system-decide-which-method-to-call-when). The relevant part is that for the second call to Format, an overload of Format(params object[]) gets expanded to Format(object[]), which is preferred to Format(object). The literal null is both an object[] and an object, but object[] is more specific, so that is chosen.

Answer (score -4):

There are two differences which are following:

1. Here, Null value is assigned.

   ```
   Exception e = null;
   string msgOne = string.Format("An exception occurred: {0}", e);
   ```
2. Here, Null value cannot be read in string format which means type casting error.

   ```
   string msgTwo = string.Format("Another exception occurred: {0}", null);
   ```

I give you simple example:
Here, You cannot read the NULL value as a string format.

```
string str = null.toString();
```