# Changing format of String.Format parameters at run time

Tags: c#, string-formatting

My older LINQ code used to have something like this:

```
DateOfBirth = string.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", myTable.DateOfBirth),
```

But now I wanted to be able to format that how ever user changes their date pattern from Windows, so I changed it to be like this and it works:

```
string regionShortDate = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
string temp = "{0:" + regionShortDate + "}";
DateOfBirth = string.Format(temp, myTable.DateOfBirth),
```

So notice I had to use string concatenations to build my string formatter?  I just think there should be a more professional way of doing this.  What do you suggest?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [DateTime.ToShortDateString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method

```
DateOfBirth = myTable.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString();
```

> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object. For example, for the en-US
>   culture, the standard short date pattern is "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE
>   culture, it is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "yyyy/M/d".
>   The specific format string on a particular computer can also be
>   customized so that it differs from the standard short date format
>   string.

And

> The value of the current DateTime object is formatted using the
>   pattern defined by the **DateTimeFormatInfo.ShortDatePattern** property
>   associated with the current thread culture. The return value is
>   identical to the value returned by specifying the "d" standard
>   DateTime format string with the ToString(String) method.

Comment: Ok will try it now, thanks. But yesterday I had situations that my code was saying like DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") and instead I wanted to use that "ToShortDateString" and in that case it didn't work as expected. Not sure why tho

Comment: @DevWannaBe, `ToShortDateString` would return you the string based on client computer culture settings. It could be `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy`, and that is what it seems you are trying to do using your code in the question

Comment: Oh Ok I read your post that explains it, see it says it is using "Culture" so like "en-US" or "en-CA"...but that's not what I want. In control panel regional settings you can still keep it in US but change the short date pattern to yy/MM/dd so it won't look at that.

Comment: yeah Culture its self depends on the Windows settings when we install it, but short date patterns that I need are not being honored by this method.

Comment: But your current code in question is referencing `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern` , Is your current code working as expected ?

Comment: Yep it is working as expected. Looks like CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern is looking at the short date patterns that we pick from the drop down in RegionLanguage settings of control panel but the "Culture" that is like "en-US", etc.. that one is separate and it comes from windows installation.  If you have access to VisualStudio give it a quick shot

Comment: @DevWannaBe, `ToShortDateString` would give you the same output as your code, I just tried in VS, selected `yy-MM-dd` as the format and DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString() returned `14-01-24`

Comment: Thanks, will test it now. One last question: my DateOfBirth is a null able type of DateTime so I should say .DateOfBirth.Value.ToShortDateString() ... do you think that is safe? assuming the older code didn't have a null exception so hopefully this should remain fine too? right?

Comment: @DevWannaBe, you need to put in place a check for `HasValue` before calling that method, otherwise you will get an invalid operation exception `Nullable object must have a value.` but not a NRE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ToShortDateString` as Habib suggests.

It depends on `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` because while `CultureInfo` holds a variety of information about matters that generally vary due to language and locality, but include personal preferences. Hence while for me while `CurrentCulture.Name` returns `en-IE`, `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` returns `2014-01-24` rather than `24/01/2014` as one would get by using the object returned from `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-IE")`, because my own rig is set up to use en-IE for language and ISO 8601 for dates and times.

Therefore, don't worry about the name of the current culture and current UI culture relating solely to its language; they can have `UseUserOverride` set to true and actually be constructed from the user's settings.

As well as Habib's suggestion, if you want to use the current short date string (or that from any other `CultureInfo` you can use the string `"d"`. This gives no advantage in your case where the short date string is all that is used, but it's useful if it will be part of a larger phrase:

```
string.Format("Today is {0:d}.", DateTime.Now)
```

(On my system, `Today is 2014-01-24.` on yours perhaps something else).

There are other [useful single-string formatting strings for dates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), that can be similarly used.

Edit:

Since you've just pointed out that you are using a `DateTime?` rather than a `DateTime`, then you've three options:

1. Use `DateOfBirth = string.Format("{0:d}", myTable.DateOfBirth)`. This results in an empty string for null cases.
2. Test for nullity with `string.Format`, e.g. `DateOfBirth = myTable.DateOfBirth.HasValue ? string.Format("Born on {0:d}.", myTable.DateOfBirth.Value) : "Date of birth unknown";`
3. Test for nullity with `ToShortDateString`; `DateOfBirth = myTable.DateOfBirth.HasValue ? myTable.DateOfBirth.ToShortDateString() : "Date of birth unknown";`.

Comment: @DevWannaBe, the reason you are not getting exception in case it if it null is because of String.Format, See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13276418/how-string-format-handles-null-values

Comment: Thanks Jon for the detailed info.