# Method overloading in C# behaving unexpectedly when using params keyword

Tags: c#, overloading, params-keyword

Ok, back to basics. I am wondering how to correctly overload a method with a `params` argument.

Here's my scenario. I start with my regular method:

```
public void MyMethod(MyObject mo)
{
    // method body
}
```

And I created an overload for it that looks like this:

```
public void MyMethod(MyObject mo, params string[] fields)
{
    // new method body

    MyMethod(mo);
}
```

The obvious intention is for `MyMethod(new MyObject());` to execute the original method and `MyMethod(new MyObject(), "field0"/*, etc...*/);` to execute the overloaded method. But that isn't what I'm finding to be the case.

What actually happens is that `MyMethod(new MyObject());` executes the overloaded method!

I don't understand that. In this type of scenario, how would I execute the original method?

### UPDATE with actual code

Okay, so here is the actual code that produces the described behavior.

Class1Base.cs:

```
public class Class1Base
{
    public virtual void MyMethod(MyObject ob)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called Class1Base");
    }
}
```

Class1.cs:

```
public class Class1 : Class1Base
{
    public override void MyMethod(MyObject ob)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called overridden method");
    }

    public void MyMethod(MyObject ob, params string[] fields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("called OVERLOADED method");
    }
}
```

MyObject.cs:

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Then, when I execute this code in this fashion:

```
var myClass = new Class1();
var myObject = new MyObject();
myClass.MyMethod(myObject);
myClass.MyMethod(null);
myClass.MyMethod(null, "string");
```

The console shows:

```
called OVERLOADED method
called OVERLOADED method
called OVERLOADED method
```

I would have expected it to show:

```
called overridden method
called overridden method
called OVERLOADED method
```

Why doesn't it?

Comment: Is it an option to just remove the old overload entirely and move it's functionality to the new overload?  As you've seen, you can supply 0 values to a `params` method and it will just create an array of size zero for the argument.

Comment: I suppose it could be an option, but for cleaner, more testable code I would prefer to use an overload. It sounds like there isn't a way to accomplish this type of overloading with the `params` keyword.

Comment: Curious.  It actually makes sense that it would be using the "overload", which in fact is acting more like a method that is "hiding" the original.  I wonder how you'd ever call the original method.  Does the compiler warn of this?

Comment: @DonBoitnott - No compiler warning.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the spec says that the `params` method should *lose* overload resolution if it is only applicable in its expanded form. Are you sure this it the behavior you're seeing? Can you show us the call sites?

Comment: What do you mean by call sites?

Comment: This might help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173339/how-does-the-method-overload-resolution-system-decide-which-method-to-call-when

Comment: @quakkels I mean can you show us the code that is actually calling these methods. I suspect there is more going on than you've shown us.

Comment: @dlev - Please see comment on you answer.

Comment: The question has been updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you're telling us the whole story. Section 7.3.5.2 of the C# 5 spec (titled "Better function member") says in part:

> • Otherwise, if MP is applicable in its normal form and MQ has a
>   params array and is applicable only in its expanded form, then MP is
>   better than MQ.

That seems to be the case here, since the `params` version needs to be "expanded" to a zero-length array. And in fact, trying your code locally produces the expected result of calling the non-`params` version.

**Update**: In response to your edit, the answer is now clear: You are calling the methods from `Class1`, which means that when performing overload resolution, methods marked as `override` are not considered initially. And since a non-overridden method is applicable (albeit in its expanded form,) that is the method chosen.

Specifically, section 7.6.5.1 read in part:

> • The set of candidate methods is reduced to contain only methods from
>   the most derived types: For each method C.F in the set, where C is the
>   type in which the method F is declared, all methods declared in a base
>   type of C are removed from the set.

The base class `MyMethod()` is excluded from the candidate set, and so it won't be selected by the algorithm.

---

The precise reasoning behind this behavior is to avoid a manifestation of the "brittle base-class" problem. Suppose we had the following class hierarchy:

```
class A
{
}

class B : A
{
    public void MyMethod(object o) { }
}
```

And the following call-site:

```
new B().MyMethod("a string");
```

That will obviously resolve to the `MyMethod()` that takes an `object`. But now suppose the creator of `A` (perhaps who works on another team) decides `A` should have a `MyMethod()`, too. So they change their class:

```
class A
{
    public void MyMethod(string s);
}
```

And now imagine what would happen if we didn't exclude methods from base types. Your call that was originally resolving to `B.MyMethod()` all of a sudden would resolve to `A.MyMethod()` (since the `string` is a better match.) The designers of C# didn't want to allow another person on a totally different team to *silently change the meaning of your code.*

For more information on brittle base-class issues, [Eric Lippert's (old) blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/) has a number of posts on the topic. Just search around a bit.

Comment: I've got the same result here. Everything working as expected.

Comment: Hmmm. I created a new sample project to recreate the error and I'm unable to duplicate. I can't post the code that is behaving this way. I'll work to recreate the behavior and post that.

Comment: Please see my question with updates which duplicate the described behavior.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed explanation. But, I don't see how that should be in play here. For example, if I change `public void MyMethod(MyObject ob, params string[] fields)` to `public void MyMethod(MyObject ob, string field)` then it works as expected. Could it be that something specific to `params` is causing this?

Comment: @quakkels You have two methods, both of which would theoretically be applicable. However, the method that is originally declared in the base class is ignored initially, so that leaves a single applicable method (the one with `params` in the derived class.) If you change the derived class version to `MyMethod(MyObject ob, string field)`, then *it is no longer applicable*, and so the base class version is once again considered.

Comment: I see. That's an interesting wrinkle.