# Passing null value to overloading method where Object and String as param in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two overloaded methods like below

```
 public class TestClass
    {

        public void LoadTest(object param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading object...");
        }
        public void LoadTest(string param)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Loading string...");
        }

    }
```

After calling this method like below it will show the output as **Loading string...** Please explain how .net handle this scenario?

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {       
            var obj=new TestClass();
            obj.LoadTest(null);
           // obj.LoadType(null);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Here Lippert explains it for constructors: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5174773/613130

Comment: If you intended to call the other overload, use `obj.LoadTest((object)null);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C# compiler takes the most specific overload possible.

As `string` is an `object`, and it can have the value of `null`, the compiler deems `string` to be more specific.

Comment: did you mean string is derived from the base class object.so string has more priority than the object.

Comment: @JEMI Not more *priority*... as `string` is an `object`, but it's more specific, it thinks (not really, machines can't think) "well, there's two methods. The parameter can apply to both of them, but `string` is more specific than object (as `string` is an `object`) so I'll resolve this call to the `string` overload."

Answer (score 4):

`null` is a valid `string`.

It will try to match the most specific type and `string` is more specific than `object`

Depending on your use you should probably remove the parameter totally in the `object` overload.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the way C# compiler prioritizes to determine which method is *better* to call. There is one rule:

*If method A has more specific parameter types than method B, then method A is **better** than method B in overload case.*

In your case, apparently `string` is more specified than `object`, that is why `LoadTest(string param)` is called.

You can refer 7.5.3.2 Better function member in [C# language specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029) to get more understanding.

Comment: is there any rule for prioritizing these things?

Comment: @JEMI: Yes, lots of rules, I have edited my answer to add C# language specification, you can refer 7.5.3.2 to get more rule

Answer (score 2):

because compiler takes the closest possible specific method that can be accessed (null to string is closer than null to object) that is available. And in this case as both as overload with string is closer, that is why it is called.

This is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) has to say

> > Once the candidate function members and the argument list have been identified, the selection of the best function member is the same in
> >     all cases:
>
> 1. Given the set of applicable candidate function members, the best function member in that set is located.
> 2. If the set contains only one function member, then that function member is the best function member.
> 3. Otherwise, the best function member is the one function member that is better than all other function members with respect to the given
>      argument list, provided that each function member is compared to all
>      other function members using the rules in Section 7.4.2.2.
> 4. If there is not exactly one function member that is better than all other function members, then the function member invocation is
>      ambiguous and a compile-time error occurs.