# Do parameters differentiate methods?

Tags: c#, parameters

If I have two methods in the same class of the same name, do the parameters help to differentiate the methods from each other to avoid conflict?

i.e.

```
Class1
{
    void CompareInput(Form1 frm) { }

    void CompareInput(Form2 frm) { }
}
```

Comment: They do - but your question makes no sense since one of the important factors in _function overloads_ is that the types are different. You've provided none.

Comment: this link should clear any questions - http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is called [Overloading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
interface ITest
{
    void F();                     // F()
    void F(int x);                // F(int)
    void F(ref int x);            // F(ref int)
    ...
    int F(string s);              // F(string)
    ...
}
```

The idea is that the compiler picks up the right function basing on the types of its arguments.

For instance, the following code would call two different functions:

```
ITest test = // get interface
test.F(0);
test.F("string");
```

Comment: "the compiler *may* pick up the right one". This says to me there's a possibility something could go wrong... Is that right?

Comment: @Ben I changed wording. The compiler should pick up the right function or complain. If you have `f(string)` and `f(int)`, it is easy and intuitive. But some cases it might be more confusing, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18310196.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The differentiation is done by the *types* of the parameters and is called [*Member Overloading*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229029(v=vs.100).aspx) (aka Method Overloading):

> A member's signature includes its name and parameter list. *Each member signature must be unique within the type. Members can have the same name as long as their parameter lists differ.* When two or more members in a type are the same kind of member (method, property, constructor, and so on) and have the same name and different parameter lists, *the member is said to be overloaded* ..

The actual method to use is chosen based upon the parameter list types *and* the type of the arguments applied at the call/usage-site.

In general the "best" selection is chosen, and examples can be found readily (eg. [Overloaded method selection logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19011863/overloaded-method-selection-logic)) for specific cases. If no matching signature is found a compiler error will be raised.