# "Ambiguous Match Found" when dynamically throwing "System.ArgumentException"

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Consider this function:

```
static void Throw<T>(string message) where T : Exception
{
    throw (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), message, (Exception)null);
}
```

Given a type `T` of `System.ArgumentException`, as the question title says, I get a runtime error of "Ambiguous Match Found".  Looking at the documentation for `ArgumentException`, the following are the public constructors:

```
ArgumentException()
ArgumentException(string)
ArgumentException(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext)
ArgumentException(string, Exception)
ArgumentException(string, string)
ArgumentException(string, string, Exception)
```

Given I am passing 2 arguments in to `CreateInstance`, and forcing the `null` to be a null `Exception`, I am struggling to understand why it is not matching the 4th constructor in the above list?

Comment: why don't you just `throw new DerivedException(..)` instead of calling this `Throw<T>` method. It doesn't seem to add any value apart from polluting your callstack.

Comment: @JakubKonecki, in reality `Throw` is an extension method on `bool`.  There's a lot of code that was `if(x) throw blah` `if(y & z) throw blah2`.  The extension method made this somewhat cleaner and (personally) I don't find the call-stack overly polluted as we know where to look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That will work:

```
static void Throw<T>(String message) 
  where T: Exception { // <- It's a good style to restrict T here

  throw (T) typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(String)}).Invoke(new Object[] {message});
}
```

Typical `Exception` has **4** or more constructors, so we'd rather point out which one we want to execute. Often, we have to check if there's a suitable constructor:

```
static void Throw<T>(String message) 
  where T: Exception { // <- It's a good style to restrict T here

  // The best constructor we can find
  ConstructorInfo ci = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(String)});

  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, ci))
    throw (T) ci.Invoke(new Object[] {message});

  // The second best constructor
  ci = typeof(T).GetConstructor(new Type[] {typeof(String), typeof(Exception)}); 

  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, ci))
    throw (T) ci.Invoke(new Object[] {message, null});
  ...
}
```

However, in your case you can put it with `Activator`:

```
static void Throw<T>(String message) 
  where T: Exception { // <- It's a good style to restrict T here

  throw (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), message);
}
```

Comment: For more information, the 2nd bit of code is what I *used* to have.  However, my derived exceptions (for better or worse - you can be the judge), have constructors such as `(string message, Exception inner = null)`, which gives a `MissingMethod` exception (because of the default parameter), hence the `null` added to take care of that.

Comment: Also, in the actual code, it *is* constrained by the `where` clause, but have amended the original question anyway.

Comment: @JakubKonecki, I think you meant to put that comment on the other answer :)

Comment: @Moo-Juice: In this case, I think, you have to use reflection: try to find out the best constructor, then the second best one, etc.

Answer (score 1):

This might work

```
static void Throw<T>(string message)
{
    Exception ex = null;
    throw (Exception)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), message, ex);
}
```

I don't know where `Exception` is on this list, but my guess is it is as specific as `string`,  otherwise there wouldn't be a problem. [How does the method overload resolution system decide which method to call when a null value is passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173339/how-does-the-method-overload-resolution-system-decide-which-method-to-call-when/5174773#5174773)

Comment: As I suspected before trying it, this produces the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1):

This call won't pass Exception type to the Activator thus matching it two at least two signatures.

Solution. When inner is null supply message only, or (message, paramName, inner)