# Can not call the method with right parameter mapping

Tags: c#

I have multiple overloaded methods. But I cannot call the right one. How to tell the compiler that I want especially "THIS METHOD" to be called "WITH THIS PARAMETERS"?

The naughty method is the second one:

```
public string Translate(string text, params object[] args)
{
    // Blah blah blah...
}

public string Translate(string text, string category, params object[] args)
{
    // Here we do some blah blah blah again...
}
```

Here when I try to call the first method like this: `Translate("Hello {0} {1}", "Foo", "Bar");` the compiler assumes that I'm calling the second method and sets the arguments as `category = "Foo"` and `args = "Bar"`.

I tried to name the parameters while calling them but it gave me some compiler errors.

```
Translate("Hello {0} {1}", args: "Foo", "Bar"); // CS1738
Translate("Hello {0} {1}", args: "Foo", args: "Bar"); // CS1740
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: "Foo" is a string and that is an exact match of your second parameter `category`. Pass an params array and it should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it's easy enough to fix but the root problem is the choice of signatures. This is a thorn that will go on stabbing. It's a place where an overload is a bad idea, and a different name is the better way to go.

Comment: Just something to notice: If it is relevant that you MUST call one specific method out of some overloaded versions, maybe you should rethink your overloaded methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To make it short: compiler found an exact match so it's preferred (the one with an argument named `category`) over the more generic one (as Lippert said about this: "*closer is always better than farther away*"). For a more general discussion see [his answer here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174773/1207195) about overload resolution with `null` values.

You may pass an array (instead of single values) like:

```
Translate("Hello {0} {1}", new string[] { "Foo", "Bar" });
```

This will match first overload because `string[]` isn't a `string` (then 2nd overload doesn't apply) and compiler automatically *translate* an array to `params` arguments (if types match).

As alternative you may transform second parameter to something that isn't an exact match (then more *generic* version will be used):

```
Translate("Hello {0} {1}", (object)"Foo", "Bar");
```

In general I would avoid this kind of overloads exactly for this reason. It would be much better to use different names for that functions because when arguments type is `object` things may become not so obvious and such errors may be subtle and you may get wrong results even if compiler doesn't complain.

Comment: I can't believe how I didn't think to use `new string[]` thing... Thanks it worked ;)