# Why is a generic method chosen when a non-generic exists?

Tags: c#, generics, overloading, overload-resolution

The program below produces this output:

```
Foo<T> called

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

So, `Foo(baz)` calls the generic `Foo<T>`, but `Bar(baz)` recurses and does *not* call `Bar<T>`.

I'm on C# 5.0 and Microsoft .NET. The compiler seems to choose the generic method, instead of recursion, when the non-generic method is an `override`.

**Where can I find an explanation for this rule?** (I had guessed that the compiler would choose recursion in both cases.)

Here is the program in its entirety:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    class Baz { }

    abstract class Parent {
        public abstract void Foo(Baz baz);
    }

    class Child : Parent {
        void Bar<T>(T baz) {
            Console.WriteLine("Bar<T> called");
        }

        public void Bar(Baz baz) {
            Bar(baz);
        }

        void Foo<T>(T baz) {
            Console.WriteLine("Foo<T> called");
        }

        public override void Foo(Baz baz) {
            Foo(baz);
        }
    }

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var child = new Child();
            child.Foo(null);
            child.Bar(null);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like to view all such situations as this as the compiler creators' way of punishing you for using inheritance...

Comment: Seems as though priority is being given to the non-overridden method in the child class over the overridden method in the child class; it may treat the overridden method as being part of the parent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the MSDN docs, priority is given to method signatures that are not overridden. Since the non-generic version of Foo is overridden, it immediately goes to the bottom of the priority of choosing a method. In general terms, the next step is to choose the most specific method possible and execute it. In the case of the Bar methods, the `Bar(Baz baz)` method will always be the most specific in your case.

> Overload resolution is a compile-time mechanism for selecting the best
> function member to invoke given an argument list and a set of
> candidate function members. Overload resolution selects the function
> member to invoke in the following distinct contexts within C#:
>
> - Invocation of a method named in an invocation-expression (Section
>   7.5.5). Invocation of an instance constructor named in an object-creation-expression (Section 7.5.10.1).
> - Invocation of an indexer accessor through an element-access (Section 7.5.6). Invocation of a predefined or user-defined operator referenced in an expression
>   (Section 7.2.3 and Section 7.2.4).
>
> Each of these contexts defines the
> set of candidate function members and the list of arguments in its own
> unique way, as described in detail in the sections listed above. **For
> example, the set of candidates for a method invocation does not
> include methods marked override (Section 7.3), and methods in a base
> class are not candidates if any method in a derived class is
> applicable (Section 7.5.5.1).**

[MSDN Overload Resolution](http://web.archive.org/web/20160311105302/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

I bolded the text that I think relates to your question.

Here's another question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173339/how-does-the-method-overload-resolution-system-decide-which-method-to-call-when) that might help out. It talks about method resolution in general. Doesn't touch on overridden methods, but helps fill in some of the process that I didn't touch on.

Comment: nice, without looking at msdn i figured out the reason!

Answer (score 1):

Overload resolution searches up inheritance chains, looking for the methods **defined** at each point.

`Child` defines `void Foo<T>(T baz)` but does not define `void Foo(Baz baz)` so `void Foo<T>(T baz)` is chosen.

Generally this makes sense; in real code if `Foo<T>(T baz)` did not do a very similar job to what `Foo(Baz baz)` in the base did when passed a `Baz`, then your design is confusing and you should pick a new name.

You can kludge things a bit with using `public new void Foo(Baz baz)` or `public new virtual void Foo(Baz baz)` to force an override to be defined in `Child` too (though here there'd need to be an intermediate step in the hierarchy so that the abstract method has an implementation) which could call `base.Foo(baz)` (to call into a base implementation) and/or `Foo<Baz>(baz)` (to call into the generic version)`, but such tricks are best avoided.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it behave like when you implement something like this

```
    void myMethod(long? l) { }
    void myMethod(int? i) { }
```

calling it with `null` will use the `int?`

adding this one

```
    void myMethod(short? i) { }
```

and still calling it with `null`, the code will switch to `short?`

maybe there is an internal order/priority being done?

now with your code, i'm giving this just to show the difference between letting the compiler decide and the programmer decide(explicit call)

this is the generic `Baz`

```
.method private hidebysig 
    instance void Bar<T> (
        !!T baz
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2060
    // Code size 13 (0xd)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldstr "Bar<T> called"
    IL_0006: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000b: nop
    IL_000c: ret
} // end of method Child::Bar
```

your implementation

```
    public void Bar(Baz baz) {
        Bar(baz);
    }
```

give this

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void Bar (
        class ConsoleApplication1.Baz baz
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x206e
    // Code size 10 (0xa)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: call instance void ConsoleApplication1.Child::Bar(class ConsoleApplication1.Baz)
    IL_0008: nop
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method Child::Bar
```

this one

```
    public void Bar(Baz baz)
    {
        Bar<Baz>(baz);
    }
```

give this

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance void Bar (
        class ConsoleApplication1.Baz baz
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x206e
    // Code size 10 (0xa)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldarg.1
    IL_0003: call instance void ConsoleApplication1.Child::Bar<class ConsoleApplication1.Baz>(!!0)
    IL_0008: nop
    IL_0009: ret
} // end of method Child::Bar
```