# Is it an expected behavior in overloading resolution?

Tags: c#, .net, overload-resolution

Let's have the following simplified code:

**UPDATE:** The methods actually returns an object with generic type `<T>`.

```
void Main()
{
    Foo<object>(null);
}

Bar<T> Foo<T>(T value) // first
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value: {0}", value);
    // return new Bar<T> ...
}

async void Foo<T>(Task<T> task) // second
{
    Console.WriteLine("Value from task: {0}", await task);
    // return new Bar<T> ...
}
```

This code fails in runtime: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` I have realized that compiler chooses the second overload of `Foo` with `Task<T>` argument. And therefore it fails when trying to await `null`.

Maybe it is correct behavior according the C# spec, but it can cause real troubles, since it is not the *right* overload that programmer wanted. If it is not a bug in specification or in compiler, shouldn't compiled show some warning in similar cases? What is the most convenient way to tell the compiler to choose the first overload?

Comment: read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Comment: Related: [How does the method overload resolution system decide which method to call when a null value is passed?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5173339/87698)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overloads are chosen based on the compile time type, not the run time type, so something like this should work:

```
void Main()
{
    object value = null;
    Foo<object>(value);
}
```

As mentioned in a deleted answer, you can also just cast it to an object first:

```
Foo<object>((object)null);
```

or

```
Foo<object>(null as object);
```

Comment: The simplest way is `Foo((object)value)`. Someone post this there, but then deleted the answer. So, now your answer is the closest.

Answer (score 2):

In overload resolution, if `null` is passed, then is chosen the method with the "most" derived type. In your case, `Task` inherits from `Object`, so `async void Foo<T>(Task<T> task)` is called.

If you called `Foo<string>(null);` then the compiler gave an error because `Task` doesn't inherit from `string` (nor `string` inherits from `Task`)

Comment: I have updated the code. Actually I cannot call the `Foo<string>` as I would get an object with a different generic argument.