# C#: Why does passing null take the overload with Object[] (but only in some cases)?

Tags: c#

Uncommenting the marked line below will cause a stackoverflow, because the overload resolution is favoring the second method.  But inside the loop in the second method, the code path takes the first overload.

What's going on here?

```
private static void Main(string[] args) {

    var items = new Object[] { null };
    Test("test", items);

    Console.ReadKey(true);
}

public static void Test(String name, Object val) {
    Console.WriteLine(1);
}

public static void Test(String name, Object[] val) {
    Console.WriteLine(2);
    // Test(name, null); // uncommenting this line will cause a stackoverflow
    foreach (var v in val) {
        Test(name, v);
    }    
}
```

Comment: I did think of that, but then why wouldn't the overloading be consistent?  Meaning how is the commented line different from what's in the loop?

Comment: In the loop, `v` is an `Object`, so it exactly matches the first overload.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Why dupe close when you can answer and get teh repz?!

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Because I'm here to improve the site and others' knowledge, not increase my imaginary internet points count

Comment: @JamesThorpe Pretty sure Bjom's comment was sarcastic...

Comment: @James Rhetorical question ;)

Comment: @Servy Yeah, I see that now... Though my comment could be better directed at others below :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second call works as you expect because `val` in the second method is of type `Object[]`, so in the `foreach`, `var v` is easily inferred to be of type `Object`. There's no ambiguity there.

The second call is ambiguous: References of type `Object` and `Object[]` can both be `null`, so the compiler has to guess which one you mean (more about that below). `null` doesn't have any type of its own; if it did, you'd need an explicit cast to do pretty much anything with it, which would be unpleasant.

Overload resolution takes place at compile time, not runtime. The overload resolution in the loop isn't based on whether `v` happens to be `null` sometimes; that won't be known until runtime, long after the overload has been resolved by the compiler. It's based on the declared type of `v`. The declared type of `v` is inferred rather than explicitly declared, but the point is that *it is known at compile time, when overloads are resolved*.

In the other call where you explicitly pass `null`, the compiler has to [infer which overload you want using an algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691336(v=vs.71).aspx) ([here's an answer in language which normal people can hope to understand](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174773/424129)) which in this case comes up with the wrong answer.

Of the two, it picks `Object[]` because `Object[]` can be cast to `Object`, but the reverse is not true -- `Object[]` is "more specific", or more specialized. It's farther from the root of the type hierarchy (or in plain English, in this case, one of the types is `Object` and the other isn't).

Why is specialization the criterion? The assumption is that given two methods of the same name, the one with the more general argument type is intended to be the general case (you can cast *anything* to `Object`), and the overload with a type farther towards the leaves of the type hierarchy will be intended to supersede the general-case method for certain specific cases: "Stick with this one for everything unless it's an array of `Object`; I need to do something different for object arrays".

That's not the only imaginable criterion, but I can't think of any other half as good.

In this case, it comes out counterintuitive, because you think of `null` as being as general as a thing can be: It's not even specifically `Object`. It's... *whatever*.

The following would have worked, because here the compiler doesn't have to guess what you mean by `null`:

```
public static void Test(String name, Object[] val) {
    Console.WriteLine(2);
    Object dummy = null;
    Test(name, dummy);
    foreach (var v in val) {
        Test(name, v);
    }
}
```

Short answer: Explicit `nulls` make a mess of overload resolution, to the point where I sometimes wonder if it might not have been a mistake on the part of the language designers to let the compiler even try to figure them out (NB "I sometimes wonder if it might..." is not an expression of dogmatic certainty; the guys who designed the language are smarter than me).

The compiler's about as smart as it can be, which is "not very". It may have sporadic fits of outright malice, but this case is just good intentions gone wrong.

Comment: Nice links.  I honestly didn't expect the compiler to be that clever.

Comment: @Lonimor You didn't think that it would be clever enough to compare the types of the expressions being used to the argument lists of the overloads of the method being called?  Short of doing virtually nothing at compile time at all, and binding everything at runtime, there really isn't any other choice.

Comment: @Servy I understand the rules it uses for method overloading.  I just didn't think that it knew the difference between null and Object dummy = null...but I suppose it makes more sense now thinking more about the clr types and references.

Comment: @Lonimor If `null` was an expression of compile time type `object` then you wouldn't be able to assign it to any variable that wasn't *also* of type `object` (without casting).  It *needs* to be of some other type to allow you to write `Foo f = null;`.  (In actuality of course, the null literal *has no type*; and it is implicitly convertible to *any* type.  This isn't really the compiler being clever, this is just the fundamental nature about the definition of the `null` literal.

Comment: @Servy Thanks...that helps.

Comment: @Servy Thanks, added that point about the (non-) type of `null` to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

When overloading, if an ambiguity is encountered, the compiler will always try to execute the most specific method.

In this case, `object[]` is more specific than `object`.

`null` can be any type, so it matches both method signatures. Since the compiler has to decide, it will opt for the `Test(string name, Object[] val)` causing a `StackOverflowException`.

Inside your **foreach** loop however, `v` is inferred to be of type `object`. Notice that now you have a typed variable.

As an `object`, `v` can either be an `object` or an `object[]` (or virtually any type), but the compiler doesn't know that, at least it won't know until runtime.

Overloading is resolved during compile time, so the only clue the compiler has is that `v` is an `object`, so it will chose to call `Test(string name, Object value);`

If you had the following line:

```
var val = new object[] { };
Test(name, val);
```

Then `Test(string name, Object[] val)` would have been called, since the compiler knows that `val` is an `object[]` at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

In your call to `Test(name, v);` your variable `v` as a Type of `Object` associated with it, even though it's value is `null` we still know "what kind of null" we have.

In your call to `Test(name, null);` that null has no type associated with it, so the compiler finds [the nearest match](http://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/) and uses that overload. The nearest match is the `object[]` overload.