# How compiler select method between 2 with similar signature?

Tags: c#, .net, enums, attributes, iconvertible

I have Enum

```
public enum ContentMIMEType
{
    [StringValue("application/vnd.ms-excel")]
    Xls,

    [StringValue("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet")]
    Xlsx
}
```

In extensions I have 2 methods to get attribute value:

```
public static string GetStringValue<TFrom>(this TFrom enumValue) 
            where TFrom : struct, IConvertible
{
    ...
}
```

and

```
public static string GetStringValue(this Enum @enum)
{
    ...
}
```

These methods have different signature, but when I execute next operation `ContentMIMEType.Xlsx.GetStringValue()` 1st method is taken.

Why this happens, cause execution of 2nd method for me is more obvious (have tried to change sort order, but doens't help).

Comment: It's the way the overload resolution works. See, for instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174773/1364007) answer - it is written for the case of a null argument, but the resolution works the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/overloading.aspx) is more.

Simply from site:

> overloading is what happens when you have two methods with the same
>   name but different signatures. At compile time, the compiler works out
>   which one it's going to call, based on the compile time types of the
>   arguments and the target of the method call.

And when compiller cannot deduct which is proper, compiller return error.

**EDIT**:

Based on [Constraints on type parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) and [Enum Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.enum?view=netframework-4.7.2) enum is struct and implement `IConvertible` so meets requirements and compiler use first matched. No conflict with Enum because Enum is lover than struct in inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: And in my case `struct, IConvertible` is more specific than `Enum`, right?

Answer (score 1):

The signature:

```
public static string GetStringValue<TFrom>(this TFrom enumValue)
```

Is a generic signature, which means that it is allowed to be treated as:

```
public static string GetStringValue<ContentMIMEType>(this ContentMIMEType enumValue)
```

Which is more specific than:

```
public static string GetStringValue(this Enum @enum)
```

And is therefore the method chosen.