# VS2019 Roslyn Compiler Generic Constraint Method Resolution

Tags: c#, roslyn

We recently found an issue in our code base, where VS2019 Compiled code fine but VS 2017 Failed.

I've created an extension method for Union which has a generic ISet as a Generic Constraint

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
public static class Extensions
{
    public static S Union<S, T>(this S self, IEnumerable<T> other) where S : ISet<T>, new()
    {
        //For simplicity issues since this is a compilation based question
        return default(S);
    }

    public static void Test()
    {
        var values = new[] { 1, 2, 3 };
        var values1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };

        values.Union(values1);
    }
}
```

Union generates a compilation error stating that the int[] is not convertible to ISet.

It was my understanding that method resolution originally ignored Generic constraints.  But it seems that this code Compiles in 2019.

I haven't seen anywhere in the release notes which states that they've resolved this bug or added a new feature to improve method resolution for generic methods.

I'm looking for more information about this matter,
Was this a bug fix by microsoft or an intended feature?

Comment: It was introduced in C# 7.3, deliberately. I must have seen a blog post about it somewhere in order to write about it in C# in Depth (it's in section 14.8.2) but I don't know exactly where.

Comment: @JonSkeet Prior this was not consider a bug it was an intended, implementation choice because of the additional complexity it would take to resolve that correct

Comment: @JonSkeet Thats was I was looking for, If you want to post that I will mark the question as resolved

Comment: It was a language design choice. I don't know about additional complexity being the driving force.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll accept the answer when the time limit allows me, Thanks for the quick resolution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's part of C# 7.3 (so you can use it in VS 2017 as well if you specify version 7.3). It's documented in the [C# 7.3 release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7-3):

> **Improved overload candidates**
>
> In every release, the overload resolution rules get updated to address situations where ambiguous method invocations have an "obvious" choice. This release adds three new rules to help the compiler pick the obvious choice:
>
> 1. ...
> 2. When a method group contains some generic methods whose type arguments do not satisfy their constraints, these members are removed from the candidate set.
> 3. ...

This wasn't a bug before - it was obeying the language specification; I don't know why the specification was originally written the way it was here. Possible reasons include:

- Expected implementation complexity
- Expected implementation performance
- Expected usefulness - anticipation that the previous behavior would be fine or even preferable to the current behavior, without realizing where it would be annoying in reality

Comment: It was the third. We know it is not "avoid complexity" because either way, the implementation must detect an error case and produce a sensible error message; the algorithm is not more or less complex if we move around at what point the generic constraint violations are checked. And there's no performance win to be had; method groups are small.

Comment: The argument that was made was: if overload resolution ignores constraints and deduces that the *best possible method given the arguments* is one that violates a constraint, then odds are pretty good that the developer either has a bad argument, or believes that the inferred type *ought* to meet the constraints; the right thing to do in this situation is to inform the developer that they have a mistaken argument or mistaken belief about their constraints. Hence, constraint checks are in the "final validation" phase, not the "remove inapplicable candidates" phase.

Comment: But this creates a tension when sometimes the C# developer says "I know which method I intended to call, and it is the one that is *less specific but does not violate constraints*". There's an argument to be made that in this case, the productivity gain of sometimes choosing the less-specific-but-it-works method wins out over the productivity loss of sometimes failing to alert the developer to a potential correctness problem.

Comment: @EricLippert: As well as the "less specific" am I right in saying the other option is "there are multiple candidates none of which is the most specific - but only one of which is actually applicable"? (I would be interested to know how often that occurs in reality compared with your "less specific" case. The two causing different errors, of course - your situation being "the chosen method is inapplicable" and mine being "I can't choose a method".) I'm sleepy though, so I may have missed something either in my thinking or your comments.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then yes, that sounds right. One of the specifically stated rules of overload resolution is "if there is exactly one applicable candidate then it automatically wins" (though such a method might not pass final validation.) Moving around checks around like this certainly can change what error message is produced. As I often point out, the hard part of overload resolution is not finding the unique best applicable method in the group. The hard part is reporting a sensible error when there is none!

Comment: If you look at the overload resolution code in Roslyn you'll see that I wrote it so that overload resolution does not simply produce a best method; rather, it produces a report that describes every method that was considered and why it was rejected. That report is then the input to the error message generator. Having that report available in the debugger was invaluable when I was trying to figure out why overload resolution was either picking the wrong method or giving a wrong error; my intention was to expose it in the Roslyn API but I don't know if that ever happened.

Comment: This conversation would make for an excellent mini-sequel to [Constraints are not part of the signature](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/12/10/constraints-are-not-part-of-the-signature/).