# Constructor Invocation in C#

Tags: c#, .net, constructor

I came across the below lines of code recently.

```
public class Program
    {
        public Program(Object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Object");
        }
        public Program(double[] dArray)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("double array");
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Program(null);
        }
    }
```

I thought the constructor with object as input parameter will be invoked whereas the constructor with input parameter as double array was invoked. I was confused here. Can anyone help me understand the reason behind this?

Comment: It's not about constructors only, this belongs to method overloading in general

Comment: Have a look at this thread [How does the method overload resolution system decide which method to call when a null value is passed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173339/how-does-the-method-overload-resolution-system-decide-which-method-to-call-when) There is a nice explanation from Eric Lippert about overloading resolution