# C# Method resolution does not work as expected at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, overloading, .net-6.0, overload-resolution

I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/5174773/787958 and the method resolution is not working as expected in my instance.

I have JSON coming into a method that I want to create a typed object from and then validate it.

```
var type = Type.GetType($"{Namespace.Models}.{typeName.FirstCharToUpper()}");
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);
var validator = new Validator();
var isValid = await validator.ValidateAsync(model);
```

The Validator class looks as such:

```
public class Validator : IValidator
{
    public Task<Boolean> ValidateAsync(Object model) { return Task.FromResult(true); }

    public Task<Boolean> ValidateAsync(User user)
    {
        if (user.Id == null || user.Id == Guid.Empty)
            return Task.FromResult(false);

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.Name))
            return Task.FromResult(false);

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
}
```

Even though at runtime, `type` is `User`, it does not call the `ValidateAsync(User user)` method, instead it calls `ValidateAsync(Object model)` method.

But, if the `type` is not dynamic at compile time and instead I do:

```
var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
```

It properly calls the `ValidateAsync(User user)` method.

Is there a proper way to have a dynamic type at compile time, but known at runtime, and have it call the expected "more specific" method?

**UPDATE**

Having any "future coder" add to the `switch` statement was not too much of an ask imo, since they would be in that class adding their new `ValidateAsync(NewModel model)` method anyways.  Utilizing `dynamic` was more along the lines of how I would like the code to be as it would not bloat the code with a possibly larger and larger `switch` statement. But, I was worried about performance impact.  So I ran a Postman runner 250 times with the `switch` statement (just `User` or default) and 250 times with `dynamic`.  The differences in performance was negligible.

Average response time with switch: 2.668ms

Average response time with dynamic: 2.816ms

So, I'm going to go with the `dynamic` solution.  Thanks!

Comment: The method is chosen at compile time, not run time, so in this code it's always going to call the method that takes an object as an argument.  If you want it to call the method that takes a `User` then you have to cast the argument to `User`.

Comment: Do not post "UPDATE" to questions to detail the answer you formed; post an actual answer

Comment: I usually don't add UPDATE unless I'm clarifying something. I did it this time to post the avg response times, which I think would be important for other people debating what solution they want to go with. I don't think it is right to put the actual answer in my question when it isn't my answer. It would be taking credit and people would be less likely to +1 an answer. I am willing to alter my UPDATE if you can clarify what you'd like me to change without me taking credit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overload resolution happens at the compile time, not in the runtime. `model` created by `var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);` will be of `object` type so compiler will expectedly select `ValidateAsync(Object model)` overload.

You may try using [`dynamic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) for late bound (runtime) resolution:

```
dynamic model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type);
var validator = new Validator();
var isValid = await validator.ValidateAsync(model);
```

But note that it comes with some performance cost.

Another option is [type testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast) and casting. For example with pattern matching can look like this:

```cs
var isValid = model switch
{
    User user => await validator.ValidateAsync(user),
    _ =>  await validator.ValidateAsync(model)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of method resolution you're thinking of happens at compile time.

If you want to resolve the method at run time you have to write the code for it yourself, e.g.

```
public Task<Boolean> ValidateAsync(Object model)
{
    return (model is User) ? ValidateAsync((User)model) : Task.FromResult(true);
}
```