# Why passing an integer matches an object method rather than premitive type method

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overload resolution and virtual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674368/overload-resolution-and-virtual-methods)

If i call this , why object method is being called?

```
Classes.Class2 c = new Classes.Class2();
c.GetJ(1);

public class Class1
{
   public virtual void GetJ(int j)
   {

   }
}

class Class2:Class1
{
    public override void GetJ(int j)
    {
       int j3 = 8;
    }

     public void GetJ(object j)
     {
        int j1 = 82;
     }
}
```

Comment: A really interesting question. The duplicate (linked above) has a bit more complex code as they didn't use built in types, but it's exactly the same behaviour. Look specifically at @EricLipperts answer.

Comment: @Anders Abel : Thanks for your link. Eric Lippert's comment is indeed enlightning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the C# 4.0 Specification ( https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029 )

> 7.4 Member lookup
>
> First, a set of accessible members named N is determined:
>
> - If T is a type parameter, then the set is the union of the sets of accessible members named N in each of the types specified as a primary constraint or secondary constraint (§10.1.5) for T, along with the set of accessible members named N in object.
> - Otherwise, the set consists of all accessible (§3.5) members named N in T, including inherited members and the accessible members named N in object. If T is a constructed type, the set of members is obtained by substituting type arguments as described in §10.3.2. **Members that include an override modifier are excluded from the set**.

I don't understand that behavior, but this is in the specification, so it is correct, even if a bit disturbing (and I have a C++ background)...

### Edit:

This is indeed a duplicate question (as correctly discovered by [Anders Abel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280222/anders-abel) in his comment).

See the original [Overload resolution and virtual methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3674368/overload-resolution-and-virtual-methods) for an explanation for this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This method

```
public void GetJ(object j)
{
    int j1 = 82;
}
```

is hiding the inherited `GetJ(int j)` because (and that's just how things work, there isn't much that can be done aside being more explicit in which method one intends to invoke) overrides are *never* used when there is an applicable non-overridden method in the same scope. So basically ... your code works as intended.

Comment: `both the IDE and the compiler should be issuing a Warning about this` : Tried it on Visual C++ 2010, vanilla install.

Comment: Now I had some coffee , turned on my brain, I'm editing this (because it is obviously off the point)