# Unexpected behavior - method overload with params array

Tags: c#, .net

My class:

```
public class Foo
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "Bar";
    }
    public string ToString(params int[] values)
    {
        return "Buz";
    }
    public void DoFoo()
    {
    }
    public void DoFoo(params int[] values)
    {
    }
}
```

When calling `ToString()` on expression of type `Foo`, the compiler chooses the overload with `params` (passing empty int array). However, when I call `DoFoo()` it picks the overload without the `params`, as expected. What is the reason?

Comment: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Overloading.aspx

Comment: I disagree this is an exact duplicate of those questions.  The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/3677779/832705 does give solid reasoning, though.

Comment: @stackuser83 I disagreed with the dupe-hammer at first as well, but the link from Eric Lippert's answer helped me: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/09/04/future-breaking-changes-part-three/